# Reverse Words in a String, while preserving the order of words - rustlang

Tags: rust

Source: https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-words-in-a-string-iii/

I want to know

1. What better could I do, regarding syntax and idioms
2. What better could I do, regarding performance

```rust
impl Solution {
    pub fn reverse_words(s: String) -> String {
        
        let mut  v : Vec<String> = Vec::new();
        let mut ss : String = String::new();
        let mut res : String = String::new();
        for c in s.chars() {
            if ( c == ' ')
            {
                v.push(ss.chars().rev().collect());
                println!("{}", ss);
                v.push(c.to_string());
                // ss = ' '.to_string();
                ss.clear();
            }
            else 
            {
                ss.push(c);
            }
        }
        v.push(ss.chars().rev().collect());
        //v.push(" ".to_string());
        //let t = v.chars().rev().collect::<String>();
        //v.reverse(); 
        for x in v.iter() {
            res.push_str(x);
        }
        //res.push_str(v[0]);
        return res;
    }
}
```